# What spectral estimation technique to use for finding sharp spectral lines?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density

At the moment, I am using the Welch's averaged modified periogram method for spectral estimation, which has the frequency resolution $f_s/N$ where $f_s$ is the sampling frequency and $N$ the window length. I get a a resolution that is about $0.1$ Hz. I would like to spectral lines from a set of noisy data and it appears that the resolution provided by this method is not enough in all cases.

What would be a better way to estimate the line components?

Comment: Uhm. Make N larger? Just a thought.